# Squaring the impulse operator

Tags: physics, quantum-mechanics

$$\hat p_r^2 = \hat p_r \hat p_r = (-i \hbar)^2\frac1 r \frac d {dr} r\frac1 r \frac d {dr} r=-\hbar^2\frac {d^2} {dr^2}r$$

This probably means:

$$\hat p_r =-i\hbar \frac1 r \frac d {dr} r$$

I'm trying to understand what is happening here. I understand the part $(-i \hbar)^2=-\hbar^2$, but not the rest. I would expect the result to be something like $-\hbar^2 * \frac1 r^2 * \frac{d^2} {dr^2} * r^2 $.

The way it seems to me now, is that multiplying operators isn't the same as multiplying numbers? But instead it means applying the first operator to the result of the later operator? That would mean (here I leave out the constants) applying $\frac1 r  \frac{d} {dr}  r$ to $\frac1 r  \frac{d} {dr}  r$ and $r * \frac1 r $ is $1$ and then we get the result.

But then, why is $\nabla * \nabla$ a dot product, considering that multiplication doesn't work the simply anymore? For example, it seems like when multiplying operators, you can't switch around order anymore. So why does the dot product rule still apply? After all, $ \Delta$ yields a number, but $\nabla$ is a vector and still yields a vecor right? Simply applying $\nabla$ twice instead of $\nabla * \nabla = \Delta$ would still yield a vector, right?

Comment: What is your definition of $\hat p_r$?

Comment: @lisyarus Added

Comment: Put in test functions like $\frac{1}{r^2} \frac{d}{dr} (r^2 \frac{df}{dr})$ and simplify. That way easier to keep track of ordering multiplying by functions and differentiating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\hat{p}_r f = - i \hbar \frac{1}{r} \frac{d}{dr} (r f)\\
\hat{p}_r^2 f = - i \hbar \frac{1}{r} \frac{d}{dr} ( r (\hat{p}_r f))\\
= - \hbar^2 \frac{1}{r} \frac{d}{dr} ( r \frac{1}{r} \frac{d}{dr} (rf))\\
= - \hbar^2 \frac{1}{r} \frac{d}{dr} ( \frac{d}{dr} (rf))\\
= - \hbar^2 \frac{1}{r} \frac{d^2}{dr^2} (rf)\\
$$

Multiplication by $r$ and operating $\frac{d}{dr}$ do not commute so keep the order in mind.

$$
r \frac{d}{dr} f = r \frac{df}{dr}\\
\frac{d}{dr} (rf) = f + r \frac{df}{dr}\\
\frac{d}{dr} ( r f) \neq r \frac{d}{dr} f\\
[r , \frac{d}{dr}] = -1
$$

In this case you aren't bothering with the $\hat{p}_\theta$ or $\hat{p}_\phi$ so no need to make $\nabla$

Comment: That makes sense! So basically multiplying operators means applying one operator to the other, and not squaring the result of one Operator? Because the second one was what I thought had to happen.